# How can I access Cloudinary's helper method in Symfony2 Controller?

Tags: symfony, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary to manage direct image uploads in my Sf2 application.

There's a Cloudinary helper function called "cl_image_upload_tag" that generates the upload form.

I need to run the function in my controller and display the results as raw code in my template.  But I'm not able to access the function in my Controller

```
$cloud_form = \Cloudinary\Uploader::cl_image_upload_tag('image_id', array("callback" => $this->get("router")->generate("cloudinary_callback")));
```

(I will output $cloud_form in Twig as {{ cloud_form|raw }} )

I think this is a namespace issue but I can't make it work, it get "Error: Call to undefined method".  Thanks!

Update: here's the autoload file:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var $loader ClassLoader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Comment: what is the actual error? could you include it into your question?

Comment: Sorry just updated, the error is "Error: Call to undefined method"

Comment: What version of symfony are you running?

Comment: Running 2.3.  The function lives in this class https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/blob/master/src/Uploader.php and I'm using composer to install the whole thing.

Comment: Could you paste the `app/autoloader.php` file?

Comment: Hi Don I just added it above thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`cl_image_upload_tag` isn't a method of the Uploader class, it's just a function defined in Uploader.php, which is the same file that holds the Uploader class.

Assuming that you include Uploader.php at the top of you controller, you can just call the function directly:

```
$cloud_form = \cl_image_upload_tag('image_id', array("callback" => $this->get("router")->generate("cloudinary_callback")));
```

If you are using composer to vendor the Cloudinary package, Composer may take care of adding those functions to your application without the need to include the file in your controller.

Comment: Hi thank you, unfortunately that's not working.  I can't just hard-code include the file in Symfony2, that should be handled by namespacing right?  I have "use \Cloudinary\Uploader;" at the top of my controller.

Comment: If you check the Uploader.php file, you will see that the functions are not part of the Couldinary\Uploader namespace. Using them requires that the file has been included, at which point they should be part of your root namespace.

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this...what is the most Symfony-way to include a vendor library file?  The paths are different on my local machine and remote server...I feel like we are doing it wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: You can do it with composer, although I'm not sure how you go about doing it from a vendor's library. Semms like something that the vendor should be doing in their composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your `app/autoloader.php` file as follows

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Cloudinary' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/path/to/Cloudinary/source/file',
));
```

From now on you should be able to refer to your class as `Cloudinary`

```
use Cloudinary; // example
use Cloudinary\Uploader; //other example
```